# How to mock protected global variables boolean in java junit test

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How to mock protected global variables boolean in Java JUnit test?

```
public abstract class Base {
  protected boolean varBoolean;

  ...

}


public class NameClass extends Base {
   private List <String> arrayStr;
   public void init() {

      if (varBoolean) {

         ...

      }

      ...

   }

}

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
@Slf4j
public class NameClassTest {
  public void testInnit() {


  }  


  ...

}
```

How to mock protected `varBoolean` be equal `true` in Java unit test?

And mock private string list arrayStr

Comment: How is the logic behind your variable?

Comment: Not thing, it's boolean.

Comment: One thing you can do  is, to extend from the production class and set the variable to true in a `@Before` annotated method

Comment: But How you can change it in the class?

Comment: In NameClassTest.class, You have an example?

Comment: something like `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
@Slf4j
public class NameClassTest extends NameClass {
@Before public void init() { varBoolean=true}
  ...

}`

Comment: As far as I can tell (though hard to be sure with the lack of context), mocking this makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can fix it.

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
@Slf4j
public class NameClassTest {

 @InjectMocks
 NameClass nameClass;


 @Test
 public void testInit() throws Exception {
    nameClass.varBoolean = true;
    nameClass.init();
    ...
 }

}
```

> nameClass.varBoolean = true;

Answer (score -1):

Add a test only constructor to NameClass with a varBoolean parameter. Call it in your test with whatever argument you want.

Comment: Adding code for tests in production class is a bad suggestion